# How do remove administrative rights if the checkbox is disabled in Users&Groups

Tags: macos, permission, administrator

By default in the second hand MacbookPro, I have a user called `admin`. Then I created another user, let me call it `myadmin` for example. Now, I want to remove the admin rights from the user named `admin`.

Screenshot:

[image]

I've rebooted, logged in directly with the new `myadmin` user and unlocked the preference pane. But I'm still unable to remove the admin rights from the `admin` user. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Ah, I see. Was the Mac currently part of a centrally managed setup? Or is the `admin` user still logged in?

Comment: @nohillside I don't know what `centrally managed setup` means. The `admin` user is not logged in. I shutdown and start the Macbook pro and login the "new" user  directly. (The user is not really new, I have been using it for a year. Today, I just want to remove admin rights from the old `admin` user which is not created by me.)

Comment: @nohillside FYI, I just did the job by using command line way and posted as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you not format the disk or put a new disk into the machine after purchase? Is definitely something that I would think about.

Comment: @FiddleDeDee that is what I will do next time. But I don't do it this time though. In the beginning, I just planed to use it as a backup laptop to compile iOS app only so I don't bother doing anything especially it has some apps pre-installed. (and I was not confident to reinstall MacOS or factory reset since I never did that before. The irony is Linux is much easier to me). But now I use it as my primary laptop, I regret that I didn't format the disk. Since there are many apps, files and my setup environment, It will take a long time to rebuild them. I will simply leave as what it is now.

Comment: Understandable - but how do you know there was no malware on there? Any backdoor connections? Hidden user accounts?

Comment: @FiddleDeDee I don't really know. If you can teach me how to make sure there is no threat, that'll be great. But since I am a long time Linux user, I kinda tried my best to avoid it. (1) Create a new admin user. (2) remove the admin rights from old user that is what I just did. (3) remove sudo without password privilege by running `sudo visudo` (4) installed BlockBlock. So far after one year usage, I think I am fine. But not 100% sure.

Comment: @FiddleDeDee your comment reminds me security again after one year, I am installing avast now. Hopefully a full system scan can prove something. 

Answer (score 1):

I just did it by using the command line way. I am not sure if this is recommended or not since I have no ideas why I can not do it in the GUI.

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -d admin -t user admin
```

The above command does the job.

*PS: Because it's a second hand Macbook pro and it's the first MacOS I ever used. I thought `admin` was a built-in user which I could not simply use the above command. But it turns out I was wrong and `admin` is not a built-in account and I can simply run the command.*

Btw, for your info, if you want to do this for other usernames:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -d <username> -t user admin
```